# Create a socket from java.io.FileDescriptor

Tags: java, sockets, file-descriptor, jnienv

I'm running a server written in Java (which may or may not be the Minecraft server) on my Linux box and I want to start it on demand using a systemd socket.  In order to do this I'm going to need to accept an already created socket object from systemd.  This is easy enough -- just call `sd_listen_fds(0)` from C code to confirm we actually got a socket, then just treat file descriptor 3 like a socket and start accepting connections (or maybe set Accept=Yes and pass the sockets through a door to the actual server process) -- but the hard part is passing that socket once we've got it back to Java.  It's easy enough to get hold of a java.io.FileDescriptor (just instantiate it with no arguments and set the "fd" property to an int) but getting from there to a socket is what I'm stuck on.  You can create a Socket from a SocketImpl, and SocketImpl objects have an fd property of type FileDescriptor but I don't know how to obtain a SocketImpl instance and I don't know if setting the fd property after creation is safe.

Comment: See `SelectorProvider.inheritedChannel()`, although you will probably want to invoke it via `System.inheritedChannel()`. You can get a `ServerSocketChannel` directly from that, and a `ServerSocket` from that if necessary.